# Filter and search Object/Array items that meet complex conditions

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

How I can find some items in JSON/JavaScript Array or Object which meets logical condition based on their values (or their parent values)?

What I'm trying to (define magicalWay function!):

```
myArray = [
            {"type":"A","items":[0,1,2,3,4]},
            {"type":"B","items":['x','y','z']}
          ];

magicalWay(myArray,"<parent>.type=='A'","<this>.items");
//and output: [0,1,2,3,4]

magicalWay(myArray,"true","<this>.items");
//and output: [[0,1,2,3,4],['x','y','z']]

myObject = {
  "type": "A",
  "items": [
    {
      "type": "B",
      "items": ['x','y']
    },
    {
      "type": "C",
      "items": [0,1]
    }
  ]
};

magicalWay(myObject,"true","<this>.items[*].items");
//and output: [['x','y'],[0,1]]
```

Any suggestion helps me :)

I think my `magicalWay` function must use `array.prototype.filter` some how:

```
function magicalWay(myVar,strCondition,strPattern){
  //replacing strCondition groups like [*] and others, and evaluate strCondition for each searching items.
  //strPattern is which path should be extract and search
  //and myVar is which searching through!
}
```

---

additional: just like MySQL JSON extracting, '$[*].items' returns all item's `items` values in one array!

Comment: What does `true` mean for the second call of `magicalWay()`. You need to add more details on what you want to achieve.

Comment: evaluating "true" for each items in path pattern means all of them are acceptable @AmreshVenugopal

Comment: So according to my understanding, you want the value of items inside an array or object based on the second argument?

Comment: extracting myVar (first arg) as third arg defines path. in this extraction, just items that meet second arg (strCondition) will be return. @AmreshVenugopal

Comment: Your proposed `magicalWay` method is primarily performing two operations: a [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map). The built-in `filter` and `map` methods on the array object should be sufficient to meet your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is to define the actual *functions* you'd use to get the results you want:

```js
var myArray = [
  {
    "type": "A",
    "items": [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
  },
  {
    "type": "B",
    "items": ['x', 'y', 'z']
  }
];

var result1 = myArray
  .filter(obj => obj.type === "A")            // Select
  .map(obj => obj.items)                      // Get nested
  .reduce((arr, cur) => arr.concat(cur), []); // Flatten

//[0,1,2,3,4]
console.log(JSON.stringify(result1));
```

You'll need to do the same for your `object` input. Once you've figured out how `filter`, `map` and `reduce` work, you can create a function with this signature:

```
function getData(source, itemFilter, propertyGetter) { /* ... */ }
```

Now, if it's a requirement to start with string based filter definitions, you'll have to parse the strings and return actual functions instead. I think the string logic you propose is a bit dangerous and hard to parse, but if you write strict tests you might get away with it... A starting point could be:

```js
const noFilter = () => true;

function getFilterMethod(str) {
  if (str === "true") {
    return noFilter;
  }
  
  const parts = str.split(".").slice(1);
  
  return (
    obj => parts.reduce((cur, key) => cur[key], obj)
  );
}

const data = [
  { items: true },
  { items: false },
  { test: 1 }
];

console.log("true:",
  JSON.stringify(data.filter(getFilterMethod("true")))
);


console.log("<this>.items:",
  JSON.stringify(data.filter(getFilterMethod("<this>.items")))
);
```

Combine the two, add the data-getter logic, and you're moving towards something like:

```
magicalWay(
  myArray, getFilterMethod("true"), getPropertyExtractor("<this>.items")
)
```

I'm not going to write the rest of the code for you, but if you have specific questions I'm happy to help!

Comment: Thank you for great answer. if I have a serious problem, I will ask again :D @user3297191